# Écart entre l'orthographe et la prononciation du français

Tags: orthographe, prononciation, histoire

Toutes les personnes ayant appris ne soit-il qu'un tout petit peu de français auront remarqué qu'il y existe un très grand écart entre la façon dont on l'écrit et la façon dont on le prononce. Par exemple : des lettres muettes à la fin de la plupart des mots ; une voyelle suivie par "n" ou "m" prononcée comme une voyelle nasale ; et la lettre "h" qui ne signifie presque plus rien du tout.

Pourquoi et quand est-ce que ces différences sont survenues ? Il y a 200 ans, l'ortographe avait-elle un lien plus serré avec la prononciation ? Il y a 500 ans, peut-être ? 1 000 ?

Comment: Voir par exemple http://www.ccdmd.qc.ca/correspo/Corr4-1/Lizotte.html en complément d'éventuelles réponses. Tl;dr pour l'époque : l'orthographe est fixée depuis le 18-19e siècle, et elle a eu un lien plus serré avec la prononciation, tout en gardant à l'esprit que pendant longtemps il n'y a pas eu de norme et que l’orthographe a été **très** variable.

Comment: Il est peu probable qu'une réponse définitive existe, et l'on peut lire dans le faq du site : What kind of questions should I not ask here? You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

Comment: Si telle est ton opinion, vote pour la clôture. Mais je ne suis pas d'accord avec toi : en effet, le lien donné par Evpok représente, si ce n'est pas une réponse définitive, au moins une réponse constructive. La question n'est ni "bavarde", ni "ouverte" (traductions très approximatives des mots employés dans le texte anglais du faq), et je te ferai aussi remarquer que les normes d'un site sur l'informatique ne sont pas forcément celles qui conviendraient le mieux à un site comme celui-ci.

Comment: Pourquoi stigmatiser le français? L'anglais est pas mal non plus avec sa demi-douzaine de façons de prononcer un 'a'.

Comment: @mouviciel , je n'ai jamais dit que l'orthographe anglaise était parfaite ! Elle est, d'après moi, bien pire que la française.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

À la lecture de [documents du 16<sup>e</sup> siècle](http://r.pinson.free.fr/calvary/pdf/geneve_1564.pdf), on voit que l'orthographe de l'époque était bien différente. Pas qu'elle ait eu plus de sens qu'aujourd'hui, mais elle était moins fixée. De façon assez amusante, les abréviations y étaient beaucoup plus courantes qu'aujourd’hui par exemple, y compris dans des textes formels, et l’on pouvait trouver un même mot orthographié de plusieurs façons différentes sur une même page.

Beaucoup des spécificités de l'orthographe et de la prononciation françaises viennent essentiellement du mélange que la langue française représente entre latin et langues germaniques. L'exemple du *h* en début de mot que tu cites est caractéristique : les mots d'origine latine ont souvent donné des *h* muets (par exemple « hôtel »), alors que dans ceux d'origine germanique, le *h* doit être prononcé (par exemple « harpe »).

La création de l'Académie Française au 17<sup>e</sup> siècle a donné lieu à l'édiction de règles d'orthographe qui ont fixé notre manière d'écrire. L'Académie continue de faire évoluer ces règles en fonction des usages (très lentement, cependant, cf. la loi sur la réforme de l'orthographe de 1990). Ces évolutions vont en général dans le sens d'une perte de l'étymologie (par exemple, suppression de la prononciation des *h* de début de mots, modification des accents dans *événement* / *évènement*, etc.), ce qui rend la langue de moins en moins liée au sens qui a justifié l’orthographe initiale de ces mots.

Answer (score 2):

Je ne suis de loin pas un expert, d'autres pourront corroborer, mais il me semble avoir lu que souvent l'orthographe 'officielle' des mots a été fixée en fonction de leur (parfois supposée) étymologie ; peut-être avec un brin d'orgueil intellectuel…

Autrement dit, là où l'on pourrait croire à une évolution de la prononciation et un écart vis-à-vis de l'orthographe attendu, il est possible que les deux aient toujours été en décalage.

Comment: @Knu: Soit pour le subjonctif. Mais pour le reste, je trouve la phrase incompréhensible maintenant.