# Pourquoi les francophones utilisent tant de lettres qu'ils ne prononcent pas?

Tags: prononciation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Écart entre l'orthographe et la prononciation du français](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/86/ecart-entre-lorthographe-et-la-prononciation-du-francais)

Par exemple, la liste suivante:

1. Sucent (/sys/ pas /sysan/)
2. Beaucoup (/boku/ pas /bokup/)
3. Pareille (/parej/ pas /pareil/)
4. Embouteillage (/embutejaj/ pas /embuteilage/)
5. Monsieur (/mosjo/ pas /monsijor/)

Comment: Cette question est un cas particulier de [l'écart entre l'orthographe et la prononciation du français](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/86/ecart-entre-lorthographe-et-la-prononciation-du-francais). Je ne crois pas qu'il y ait beaucoup plus à dire spécifiquement sur les lettres muettes.